# Objective Equivelent to base16().decode(String)

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, hmac

Currently our team is working on an HMAC key but the results on iOS and Android are different. The Java part is working fine but the iOS part appears not to be working.

We have established that the problem is with the HMAC_KEY in java the key first gets converted to a base16 byte[]. What would be the Objective-C equivelent to the following?

```
        byte[] hmacKey = BaseEncoding.base16().decode(HMAC_KEY);
        SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(hmacKey, HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
        mac.init(signingKey);
        byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes(C_UTF8));



        return BaseEncoding.base64().encode(rawHmac);
```

curently in ios we have the following:

```
NSData *saltData = [salt dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *paramData = [signingData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableData* hash = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH ];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, saltData.bytes, saltData.length, paramData.bytes, paramData.length, hash.mutableBytes);
NSString *base64Hash = [hash base64Encoding];
```

the problem is withing the `BaseEncoding.base16().decode(HMAC_KEY)` part how do we do this in Objective-C?

Answer (score 0):

From your Java code, you need to convert HMAC_KEY(HexDecimalString) to NSData first, then you can do HMAC_SHA256 Calculation. This is my Swift solution

```
public extension String {

    func sha256(key: NSData) -> String {
        let inputData: NSData = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!
        let keyData = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(key.bytes)

        let algorithm = HMACAlgorithm.SHA256
        let digestLen = algorithm.digestLength()
        let result = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.alloc(digestLen)

        CCHmac(algorithm.toCCHmacAlgorithm(), keyData, key.length, inputData.bytes, Int(inputData.length), result)
        let data = NSData(bytes: result, length: digestLen)
        result.destroy()
        return data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
    }

    func dataFromHexadecimalString() -> NSData? {
        let data = NSMutableData(capacity: characters.count / 2)

        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[0-9a-f]{1,2}", options: .CaseInsensitive)
        regex.enumerateMatchesInString(self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, characters.count)) { match, flags, stop in
            let byteString = (self as NSString).substringWithRange(match!.range)
            var num = UInt8(byteString, radix: 16)
            data?.appendBytes(&num, length: 1)
        }

        return data
    }
}

enum HMACAlgorithm {
    case MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512

    func toCCHmacAlgorithm() -> CCHmacAlgorithm {
        var result: Int = 0
        switch self {
        case .MD5:
            result = kCCHmacAlgMD5
        case .SHA1:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA1
        case .SHA224:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA224
        case .SHA256:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA256
        case .SHA384:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA384
        case .SHA512:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA512
        }
        return CCHmacAlgorithm(result)
    }

    func digestLength() -> Int {
        var result: CInt = 0
        switch self {
        case .MD5:
            result = CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA1:
            result = CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA224:
            result = CC_SHA224_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA256:
            result = CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA384:
            result = CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA512:
            result = CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH
        }
        return Int(result)
    }
}
```

You can simply get base64Hash like this and the result was verified:

```
print(dataString.sha256(HMAC_KEY.dataFromHexadecimalString()))
```